# Inputs for Binomial Heaps

Tags: algorithms

This is my first question here. I was studying binomial heaps and it time analysis. 
Can there be any inputs that cause DELETE-MIN, DECREASE-KEY,and DELETE to run in Big-omega(log n) time for a binomial heap rather than Big-O(logn)

Thanks

Comment: Welcome to MSE! Are you sure this is the right forum or did you want the [**Programmers**](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions) SE? Regards

Comment: Actually, [Computer Science.SE](http://cs.stackexchange.com/) is probably the right place for this (not Programmers).  This is squarely within the scope of CS.SE.

Answer (score 1):

All those operations take $\Theta(\log n)$ time which is both $O(\log n)$ and $\Omega(\log n)$ time. Did you mean $\omega(\log n)$? In which case the answer is no for the reason I just gave. See chapter 20 of CLRS or http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_heap for example.